# Calling a method every x minutes

Tags: c#, timer, periodictimer

I want to call some method on every 5 minutes. How can I do this?

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*** calling MyMethod *** ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*** Method is executed at {0} ***", DateTime.Now);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.Threading.Timer`

Comment: or System.Timers.Timer - http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

Answer (score 225, accepted):

```
var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
{
    MyMethod();   
}, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

Edit - this answer is out of date. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70887955/426894

Comment: Another way to set the interval is by passing in a timespan object. I think it's a little bit cleaner: [`Timespan.FromMinutes(5)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromminutes.aspx)

Comment: I think there's a problem with the timespan object because it's not the right type (as is), compared to just `0, 5 * 60 * 1000`. Anyway, for me it generates an error.

Comment: @amiregelz Go ahead and post a new question, commenting on a year old answer isn't likely to get much help for you.

Comment: @asawyer I don't have any issue, just wanted to let you know this code gives an error.

Comment: @amiregelz Hmm... well I have this exact code running in production. What exactly is the error your seeing?

Comment: @asawyer Oh then maybe it's not a real issue. It was a type error, I think the timespan returns double and the timer function needs an int or something like that. Maybe the other way around. Not something critical of course, but some people that copy the function from here might run into this problem too, I think.

Comment: @asawyer Unfortunately your implementation gives a compile error. `TotalMilliseconds` returns a double while the timer expects integers or `TimeSpan`. I tried to update your answer to one that employs `TimeSpan` and throws out unnecessary bloat; however, you reverted it.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen Change 0 in Time constructor to TimeSpan.Zero. Code works after this.

Comment: @RredCat Thanks! I contributed a similar solution lower down: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21590665/604048

Comment: Code gives an error. This is the fix

   new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
   {
    Func();
   }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds);

Comment: This gives a compile error for me in Visual Studio 2015. Please fix as the comments have suggested.

Comment: Important note: when I tried to implement it with TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x) it was unable to run each number of seconds only when I back to use minutes it starts working again

Comment: What is the null value?

Comment: It is important to mention that a `System.Threading.Timer` needs to be rooted, otherwise it is eligible for garbage collection. So just storing it in a local variable `timer` will not cut it. Relevant question: [System.Threading.Timer not firing after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635852/system-threading-timer-not-firing-after-some-time).

Answer (score 63):

I based this on @asawyer's answer. He doesn't seem to get a compile error, but some of us do. Here is a version which the C# compiler in Visual Studio 2010 will accept.

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
    e => MyMethod(),  
    null, 
    TimeSpan.Zero, 
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Comment: Commenting for posterity. It would stop when you called `Dispose()` method on the timer object. Example:

`timer.Dispose()` using the code above as a reference. This will destroy the timer, however and prevent you from using it again. `timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)` would be better if you want to use the timer again in the same program.

Comment: But why does MyMethod() not run when I run it in console application

Comment: @Izuagbala It's hard to say why it doesn't work for you without knowing the particulars of how you have set it up. This solution was tested in a console application.

Comment: What is the null?

Comment: @DanielReyhanian You can add an object state instead of the `null`, that is as a argument when calling the callback function (i.e., the first argument).

Answer (score 52):

### Update .NET 6

For most use cases in dotnet 6+, you should use the [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer):

```cs
var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    //Business logic
}
```

This has several advantages, including async / await support, avoiding memory leaks from callbacks, and [`CancelationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) support

#### Further Reading

- [API proposal: Modern Timer API](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31525)
- [Execute specified function every X seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6169288/1366033)
- [Why there are 5 Versions of Timer Classes in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10317088/1366033)
- [A New Modern Timer API In .NET 6 - PeriodicTimer](https://www.ilkayilknur.com/a-new-modern-timer-api-in-dotnet-6-periodictimer)

Answer (score 13):

Start a timer in the constructor of your class.
The interval is in milliseconds so 5*60 seconds = 300 seconds = 300000 milliseconds.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 300000;
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
}
```

Then call `GetData()` in the `timer_Elapsed` event like this:

```
static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //YourCode
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Example of using a `Timer`:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Timer t = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds); // Set the time (5 mins in this case)
    t.AutoReset = true;
    t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(your_method);
    t.Start();
}

// This method is called every 5 mins
private static void your_method(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("..."); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've uploaded a Nuget Package that can make it so simple, you can have it from here [ActionScheduler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ActionScheduler/)

*It supports .NET Standard 2.0*

And here how to start using it

```
using ActionScheduler;

var jobScheduler = new JobScheduler(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(8), new Action(() => {
  //What you want to execute
}));

jobScheduler.Start(); // To Start up the Scheduler

jobScheduler.Stop(); // To Stop Scheduler from Running.
```

Comment: Could not install package 'CrystalJobScheduler 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Timer`. [Timer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Using a DispatcherTimer:

```
 var _activeTimer = new DispatcherTimer {
   Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
 };
 _activeTimer.Tick += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) { 
   YourMethod(); 
 };
 _activeTimer.Start();
```

Comment: Just want to point out that if you want to do it every ``x`` seconds, then you can do, ``TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x)``

Comment: Yeah, but the OP needed it in minutes. :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved by applying while loop and calling `Thread.Sleep` at the end of the loop.

```
while (true)
{
    //Your code
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Make sure to include `using System.Threading`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more complicated time executions such as linux cron, you can use NCrontab.

I use NCrontab in production for long time and it works perfect!

[Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ncrontab/)

How to use:

```
* * * * *
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
| | | +------- month (1 - 12)
| | +--------- day of month (1 - 31)
| +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

```
using NCrontab;
//...

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  // run every 5 minutes
  var schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse("*/5 * * * *");
  var nextRun = schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
  logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);    
  do
  {
    if (DateTime.Now > nextRun)
    {
      logger.LogInformation("Sending notifications at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
      await DoSomethingAsync();
      nextRun = schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
    }
    await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
  } while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
}
```

Add seconds if you need:

```
// run every 10 secs
var schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse("0/10 * * * * *", new CrontabSchedule.ParseOptions { IncludingSeconds = true });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(60 * 5 * 1000);
    Console.WriteLine("*** calling MyMethod *** ");
    MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: yup if anything use await Task.Delay(60 * 5 * 1000);

Comment: I like this answer, much simpler than any Timer above.

Comment: I think sleep makes the whole app freeze!