# How to call web service with interval of five minutes?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have this code:

```
class ServiceConsumer
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         //call from here retriveEvents method evry 5 minutes!
    }


    private static void retriveEvents()
    {

        IContract proxy = ChannelFactory<IContract>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(),
                                        new EndpointAddress("http://someAddress/Hydrant.svc"));

        using (proxy as IDisposable)
        {
            var rows = proxy.GetData(new DateTime(2000, 5, 1));
        }
    }
}
```

The retriveEvents() method is creating proxy and retrieve data from host service.
How can I call asyncroniusly retriveEvents() method to access host service evry 5 minutes?

Comment: Use a timer (tick)?

Comment: This answer should work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21590665/2290059. Don't forget to wait from the main thread by invoking `Console.ReadLine();` for example.

Comment: @YacoubMassad, can I use while loop instead of Console.ReadLine(); ?

Comment: That wouldn't be a good idea because it would keep one CPU core busy doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
   aTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
   aTimer.Interval=360000;
   aTimer.Enabled=true;

   while(true) { }
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     // Do your stuff
     retriveEvents();
}
```

Comment: I tried it. It goes threw all rows in main function  but it never fires  OnTimedEvent method

Comment: I would use `System.Timer.Timer` instead of `System.Threading.Timer` because it is threadsafe out of the box.

Comment: @Michael have you added a while(true) loop? because otherwise you program stops before calling the `retriveEvents`

Comment: yes!I tried this one   aTimer.Interval=360000;

Comment: and the `while(true)`? I changed it in the code above

Comment: wow! `while(true) { }` will max out the CPU!

Comment: Is the reason really the `while(true)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
{
    MyMethod();
}, null, 0, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds);
```