# Update timer thread get closed

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am updating a label of a popup every 5 minutes and have based the code on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019433/calling-a-method-every-x-minutes).

```
public MyPopup()
{
   var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
   var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

   var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
   {
     UpdatePopupUI();
   }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
}
```

Everything works fine but when I get back to the main windows and open new windows (not a new instance of the popup) it seems that the thread get deleted. I get no error in the input windows. Any idea regarding what can be killing the thread? Is there a way that I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: Timer goes out of scope, make it a class property

Comment: Thanks for the fast an efficient input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your objects get garbage collected. Store your timer variable permanently, maybe in a static variable.

Comment: Or you can use [`GC.KeepAlive(timer)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx) explictly - but that is probably not appropriate for this particular code.