# Execute a function until 5 minutes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

In a WPF form I'm calling doSomeFunction() method in a while loop. This will run until `x == y` which works properly.

```
while (x != y)
{
   doSomeFunction();
}
```

I need to add additional functionality, which needs to check this condition until 5 minutes only. After the 5 minutes if `x != y` I need to return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a method every x minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019433/calling-a-method-every-x-minutes)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Please read the question. Here I'm asking to call method for a 5 minutes. But in your link showing answer for call a method in each 5 mins again and again.

Comment: well you are right that's not the correct duplicate. Maybe i got lost into all the tab I got from the google search. [look](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fb6b6f4f-ae2f-44f4-9b31-8ac92b311049/exit-while-loop-after-x-minutes?forum=csharpgeneral), let me find the equivalent of this on Stackoverflow. So I will be damned if t was not a dupe. Dupe are not bad things. If you didn't find the solution while looking for it. One must make the already existing solution more visible so anyone could find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much cleaner and clear approach, You can also make use of stopwatch

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
while (x != y && stopwatch.Elapsed.Minutes <=5)
{
  doSomeFunction();
 }
stopWatch.Stop();
```

Comment: Note that this will block the UI for 5 minutes!

Answer (score 2):

You can take the  EnterTime time and check

```
 DateTime EnterTime = DateTime.Now;
 while (x != y && EnterTime.AddMinutes(5) >= DateTime.Now)
  {
      doSomeFunction();
   }
```

If both conditions are true then loop will execute

Comment: Note that this will block the UI for 5 minutes!

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Yes, I know. but he never mentioned that he is using it for UI may be a background work.

Comment: I'm using this inside a back ground worker. Will that be a issue?

Comment: @Tom - That depends on where and how you are calling it. We can't tell unless you show us the full code

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Task library and specify a timeout.

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (x != y)
        {
            // if actions are being performed on UI controls then please do invoke
            Console.Write("test");
        }
    }).Wait(millisecondsTimeout:30000);
```

Comment: It will run for 30000 millisec even though the condition is false. Hence it is not the correct solution

Comment: @VikasGupta true, on the other hand in the case your answer the time condition is useless, since in case x==y the loop will exit straightaway, and there is no in between code that might delay checking the condition. Also user did state that he want to check the condition until 5 mins. I think there is a bit of ambiguity in the question, though since the user has accepted your answer, it must be the right functionality....just that the timestamp check makes no sense if x==y, the only place it works is when x!=y initially and then switches to x==y, in that case there is a difference....

Comment: ahh got it now, yeah will update the answer with a cancellable task, but agreed your answer is much simpler then,.....also from comments the user is already on the background thread.