# Load Lib.Vlc player for specific time

Tags: c#, winforms, libvlc

Below is my code to embed lib.vlc in my winform application. I want to play it for say 5 minutes and then close automatically. How is it possible?

```
private void PlayerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Core.Initialize();
    _libVLC = new LibVLC();
    _videoView.MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);
    _videoView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    // Add it to the form
    Controls.Add(_videoView);
    var uri = new Uri(videolink);
    var media = new Media(_libVLC, uri, ":input-repeat=65535");
    _videoView.MediaPlayer.Media = media;
    _videoView.MediaPlayer.Play();

    //Set fullscreen
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.Size = screen.Bounds.Size;
    this.Location = screen.Bounds.Location;
}
```

want that player to load for 5 minutes and then close automatically.

Comment: You could create a timer that runs for an elapsed time of 5 minutes then it will remove stop the VLC player and remove the control from the `Controls` collection. How to setup timer for X minutes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13019471/13108684

Comment: Another option; There is a `--run-time` option for the Media object. Then when the media is no longer playing, simply exit.