# Timer stops being invoked

Tags: c#, timer

I have a windows service that needs run a method every 1 min.
I'm using a  System.Threading.Timer and it works fine for  30-35 min and then the method stops running without any error

My code looks like this

Variables

```
private static int intervalSend = 60000;
private TimerCallback callback;
private static Timer sendTimer;
```

Init

```
   callback = new TimerCallback(SendAliveInquiry);
   sendTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, 0, intervalSend);
```

Method

```
private void SendAliveInquiry(object obj)
{
  Method logic
}
```

Any idea why it stops running after a while?

Comment: Exceptions? Bad temper? Weather? Tim lost his wallet? It's practically impossible to give a definitive answer. Do you log errors? Do you catch and handle exceptions? Does the service enter a stopped state, or just not respond?

Comment: Also, I think that you should have it as a scheduled task. Take a look at [Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx).

Comment: This looks like a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635852/system-threading-timer-not-firing-after-some-time which suggests your sendTimer variable is being garbage collected. As in that answer; can you guarantee your static is not being disposed ? Can you post a small reproducible whole program we can test with ?

Comment: The service do not stop and still complete other task(send / receive on a message queue). I log error but nothing seem to crash.

Comment: Why is the timer static? Why is callback not static? In which class is the timer created? Is this instance garbage collected?