# System.Timers.Timer is not stopping

Tags: c#, timer

I have created a `System.Timers.Timer` and im quite new to it. So I have used the Windows Forms Timer before and now I want to use this timer for a console application.
My problem is that my timer is not stopping after one `OnTimeEvent()` and I don't know why.

```
class SortingSysFinal
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.Interval = 1000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
            
        Console.Read();
    }   
        
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", e.SignalTime);
        aTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in this line in your `Main` method:

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

You are creating a new local `Timer` object which is not the `aTimer` static member of your class.
`OnTimedEvent` does get called, but it in this line: `aTimer.Stop()` it is attempting to use the `aTimer` static member which is `null` due to missing initialization (and therefore throws an exception).

To fix it, change the line above to:

```
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

This will initialize the static member of your class as I believe you intended, and will enable the handler to stop the timer.

**Note** that `System.Timers.Timer` is not thread-safe. The `Elapsed` handler is called on a separate thread (see: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-7.0)), and therefore you need to synchronize calline `Stop()` with a lock, or even better: use [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-7.0) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This line throws a `NullReferenceException`:

```
aTimer.Stop();
```

The reason is that the static field `aTimer` is not initialized. You might think that you initialized it in the `Main` method, by you didn't. You assigned the `new System.Timers.Timer()` to a local variable, instead of the static field. Here are some suggestions and remarks:

1. Name your fields with an underscore `_` as prefix. For example `_timer`. This is a widely adopted practice, and helps immensely at differentiating between fields and local variables.
2. In this case you don't need a static field. You can get a reference to the timer by casting the `object source` argument: `var timer = (System.Timers.Timer)source;`.
3. Be aware that any exception thrown by the [`Elapsed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed) event handler is suppressed. Essentially there is a giant and invisible `try { /*...*/ } catch { }` around your code, that prevents the exception form surfacing. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed#remarks), *"this behavior is subject to change in future releases of .NET Framework"*. The chances of this behavior ever changing are zero. Despite what Microsoft says, they never do breaking changes like this.
4. The `System.Timers.Timer` [is not thread-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer#thread-safety). Also it is not impossible for the `Elapsed` event to be invoked in overlapping manner. So calling the `Stop` method inside the event handler, results in undefined behavior (by the docs). If you want to play by the book, you should synchronize the `Stop` call (and all other interactions with the timer) with a [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement).

My suggestion is to **not** use the `System.Timers.Timer` class. IMHO it's not a well designed component. Use a [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) instead. Just make sure that your `System.Threading.Timer`s are rooted (you store a reference to them somewhere), because otherwise [they are eligible for garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635852/system-threading-timer-not-firing-after-some-time) (unlike the `System.Timers.Timer` which is rooted by itself).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `AutoReset` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.autoreset?view=net-7.0) to `false` (the default is `true`).

This will ensure your callback only gets invoked once.