# Problems with function called by System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I created a Windows service that runs some tasks from time to time so I used `System.Threading.Timer`. But on some occasions, I noticed that the function stops being called.

I checked by writing to a log file that you can check where the program is possibly stopping. All executions of the called function are finished, but at some point it stops being called

Here's my code:

```
namespace Service
{
    public partial class Service: ServiceBase
    {
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            // do some stuff
            log("Service Started"); // function that write in .txt file
            // define delay and execution interval
            Timer timer = new Timer(this.OnTimer, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        }
        
        public void OnTimer(object state)
        {
            log("Function fired"); 

            // do something

            log("Function closed");
        }
        
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            log("Service stopped");
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to investigate or do to ensure the function is always called? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check Event viewer and see if there is a related error.  A service is started using a Default System Account which does not have any Environment.  Best way of starting a service is to create a Service Account with an Environment which will solve many issues.  The start the Service using Run As with the Service Account.

Comment: Related: [System.Threading.Timer not firing after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635852/system-threading-timer-not-firing-after-some-time). Keep a reference of your timer, or use the constructor [that takes a single argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor#system-threading-timer-ctor(system-threading-timercallback)) which makes it keep a reference of itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check "Function closed" per each "Function fired".
2. Check "log" doesn't break.
3. Run a task in OnTimer to isolate the executed code from the timer.
4. Dispose the timer on stop. It requires a class field which also prevents the timer to be disposed by the garbage collector.
5. Envolve error handling to track errors and to prevent the service to crash.

```
namespace Service {
    public partial class Service: ServiceBase {
        Timer _timer;
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
            // do some stuff
            log("Service Started"); // function that write in .txt file
            // define delay and execution interval
            _timer = new Timer(OnTimer, null, 5000, 60000);
        }
        public void OnTimer(object state) {
            Task.Run(() => {
                try {
                    log("Function fired"); 
                    // do something
                    log("Function closed");
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { log(ex.ToString()); }
            });
        }
        protected override void OnStop() {
            _timer.Dispose();
            log("Service stopped");
        }
    }
}
```